# Using Autotest in the Simplest Possible Way

Tags: ruby, autotest, continuous-testing

I'm new to using Autotest to continuously run rspec specs.  I'd like to simply use Autotest to work with two files: `[filename].rb` and `[filename]_spec.rb`, but when I run Autotest in the directory those files are in, it doesn't pick up changes. What am I doing wrong? I've googled and can't find an answer to this very simple scenario.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you skip autotest all together and instead use Guard, https://github.com/guard/guard and with the guard-rspec plugin.
https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec

Ryan Bates also has as screencast about guard that is worth checking out.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard

Comment: I'll try that out, but if you wouldn't mind answering my original question that would be great.